# How to get the list of predefined colors in xcolor such that the list can be used in foreach looping?

Tags: color, loops, foreach

I need to get the list of predefined colors in xcolor. Hard-coding as follows is not a good coding practice.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{minimal}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pstricks} 

\begin{document}
    \psforeach{\nA}
    {
        Tan, 
        RedOrange, 
        Magenta,
        Yellow,
        Green,
        Red,
        Blue,
        BrickRed,
        DarkOrchid,
        Rhodamine,
        OliveGreen,
        Mahogany,
        Goldenrod%      
    }{{\color{\nA}\nA} \endgraf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

My real scenario is to create an animation as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames,cmyk]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\temp{}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\DefineNamedColor[4]{\listgadd{\temp}{#2}}
\input{dvipsnam.def}
\endgroup
\def\do#1{#1,}
\edef\MyNames{\dolistloop{\temp}end}

\begin{document}
\psforeach{\x}{\MyNames}
{
   \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\x}{end}{}
   {
        \pspicture(\LL,\BB)(\RR,\TT)
        \pscircle*[linecolor=\x](0,0){\RR}
        \rput(0,0){\tiny\x}
        \endpspicture
        \newpage
   }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You find the macros in the updated answer.

Comment: @xport: Nice one :-)

Comment: @xport: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following example I use the orig `dvipsnm.def` where the colors are definied:

**EDIT 2:**

Macro to use psforeach.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{minimal}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pstricks} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring}
\def\mydvipsnamecolors{}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\DefineNamedColor[4]{%
  \listgadd{\mydvipsnamecolors}{#2}%
  }
\input{dvipsnam.def}
\endgroup
\begin{document}
All names:
\def\do#1{#1, }
\dolistloop{\mydvipsnamecolors}

Package \verb+xstring+
\begin{flushleft}
\def\do#1{#1,}
\edef\MyNames{\dolistloop{\mydvipsnamecolors}notcolor}
\psforeach{\nA}{\MyNames}{%
    \IfStrEq{\nA}{notcolor}{}{\mbox{\color{\nA}++\nA++} \quad}
}
\end{flushleft}

Package \verb+etoolbox+
\begin{flushleft}
\def\do#1{#1,}
\edef\MyNames{\dolistloop{\mydvipsnamecolors}notcolor}
\psforeach{\nA}{\MyNames}{%
   \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\nA}{notcolor}{}{\mbox{\color{\nA}++\nA++} \quad}
}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 3**

The following should also work. You don't need any psforeach:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{pst-xport}
\SetCan{1}
\SetPad{0cm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\mydvipsnamecolors{}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\DefineNamedColor[4]{%
  \listgadd{\mydvipsnamecolors}{#2}%
  }
\input{dvipsnam.def}
\endgroup
\begin{document}

\def\do#1{%
        \pspicture(\LL,\BB)(\RR,\TT)
        \pscircle*[linecolor=#1](0,0){\RR}
        \rput(0,0){\tiny#1}
        \endpspicture
        \newpage

}%
\dolistloop{\mydvipsnamecolors}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no need to redefine the colors, because they have already been defined. It was a bit trickier doing the same for `svgnames`.

Comment: @xport: I edited my code -- Now it works.

Comment: @egreg: I saw your solution and "great".

Comment: `\listgadd` does not produce a list usable with `\psforeach`, as it is not comma separated.

Comment: @egreg: Use `do` -- I edit my post

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\def\showdvipsnamescolors{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand\DefineNamedColor[4]{\color{##2}##2\par}%
  \input{dvipsnam.def}\endgroup}
\def\showsvgnamescolors{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand\preparecolorset[4]{\process##4;,,,;}
  \def\process##1,##2,##3,##4;{%
    \if!##1!\else\color{##1}##1\par\expandafter\process\fi}%
  \input{svgnam.def}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
DVIPSNAMES

\showdvipsnamescolors
\newpage
SVGNAMES

\showsvgnamescolors
\end{document}
```

It's trivial to modify the code in such a way that it produces a list of colors:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\dvipscolorslist{}
\def\showdvipsnamescolors{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand\DefineNamedColor[4]{\gappto\dvipscolorslist{##2,}}%
  \input{dvipsnam.def}\endgroup}
```

A similar redefinition can be used for `\showsvgnamescolors`:

```
\def\svgnamescolorslist{}
\def\showsvgnamescolors{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand\preparecolorset[4]{\process##4;,,,;}
  \def\process##1,##2,##3,##4;{%
    \if!##1!\else\gappto\svgnamescolorslist{##1,}\expandafter\process\fi}%
  \input{svgnam.def}\endgroup}
```

Comment: Sometimes I should use the refresh button :-)

Comment: My code shows *all* the predefined color with the options `dvipsnames` and `svgnames`. Why bother with an inappropriate macro? Without knowing the "real scenario" what do you think we should do?

Answer (score 3):

The `etoolbox` package usually helps me when I have to iterate elements in a list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\DeclareListParser*{\myforeach}{,}

\newcommand*\mycolor[1]{%
\color{#1}#1\par%
}

\newcommand*\drawcolors[1]{%
\myforeach{\mycolor}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\drawcolors{Tan,RedOrange,Magenta,Yellow,Green,Red,Blue}

\end{document}
```

Note that I'm a casual `etoolbox` user, I'm certainly unaware of the advanced stuff. `=)`